# Node.js and send back data to all browser tabs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Node.js and it works well with only one window or tab. But I want to get returned data from Node.js in all open tabs of the user's browser.

like facebook `Like` which notify in all your open tabs.

This is my regular emiting code:

```
users[user_id].socket.emit( 'xx', { data } );
```

but `data` is only available in first open tab. How can I get it in all my open tabs?

Comment: i don't see exactly what you mean. Could you clarify?

Comment: You need an array of sockets.

Comment: like facebook `Like` which notify in all your open tabs.

Comment: @SLaks I dont mean all `users`, all tabs of a specific user.

Comment: So? If each user can have multiple sockets, you still need an array.

Comment: each tab means a socket ?!

Comment: could you please write an array as an example. thanks :)

Comment: You'll need each tab to maintain an open connection to the server of some sort.  A good starting point for learning about this is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)

Comment: @broofa I am currently using node.js .

Comment: "Comet" isn't a specific product - it's generic term that refers to a variety of technical solutions for pushing data from server -> client.  E.g. You can do traditional polling, long-polling, streaming HTTP, WebSockets ... pick your poison.  With Node.js, the SocketIO is pretty popular.  Regardless of what you use, though, your server will need to maintain a list of all clients with active, open connections to your server.  Then when you have data to send, you'll need to broadcast that data to all connected clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Socket.io and that `users` is an object that you add a `user_id` to on new connections, what is probably happening is that each new socket connection with the same `user_id` is overwriting the previously cached socket. This is because object keys need to be unique otherwise setting the same key of an object essentially becomes an update or overwrite to that value.

You might be interested in [rooms](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms). Alternatively, one potential solution is turning the object value for the user into an array that you push to on new connections and splice from on disconnects. When you want to send a message, you'd iterate over the user's array and emit to each socket in the array accordingly.

Comment: well, in using array or rooms, while number of simultaneous connections increases to 10,000 users and each one has an array. this would not effect on performance ?

Comment: Sure, but that sort of scale will impact performance regardless of the implementation. I do not know which approach may be the most performant though.